# why there is no static library for math functions?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fedora, libm

Is it a standard to have only dynamic libraries mostly without their static version? I am particularly asking about math library. In my fedora 17 (linux machine on Intel 32 processor), I have latest gcc and it has libm-2.15.so and symbolic link file libm.so  but there is no libm.a.

Is libm.a missing on my system?

Comment: This is likely to be very specific to your distrubtion, but my ubuntu 13.04 has libm.a located at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a. Have you looked properly in all the possibile places libs can be stored?

Comment: @Troy I did a search at the root for libm.a but no luck. is there any other way to check its presence on my system? I use fedora 17.

Comment: Did you install the static libraries?  `yum install glibc-static`

Comment: You did `find / -name "libm.a"`? I'm not really familiar with fedora so I'm not sure how best to locate what pkg should provide it. I suspect almost all linux distros would be provide libm.a tho.

Comment: @Nirk That should be the answer .... :)

Comment: @Nirk  nicely pointed out. libm.a was missing on my system because glibc-static was not installed. thanks a lot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Install the static libraries:

```
# yum install glibc-static
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Is it a standard to have only dynamic libraries mostly without their static version?

In Fedora, it is indeed standard to only package dynamic libraries. From the [packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Packaging_Static_Libraries):

*Packages including libraries should exclude static libs as far as possible (eg by configuring with --disable-static). Static libraries should only be included in exceptional circumstances. Applications linking against libraries should as far as possible link against shared libraries not static versions.*

and later,

*In general, packagers are strongly encouraged not to ship static libs unless a compelling reason exists.*

... which goes on to say that when such a library *is* packaged, it should be in a separate subpackage with the suffix `-static`, as in this case `glibc-static`.

Answer (score 0):

generally the .somand .a exist at the same time, but dll comes first.

maybe the static library is missing, you can try yum command as nirk said.