# Fedora dynamic replacement for libm.a(static lib)?

Tags: c, static-libraries, fedora, libm

I'm just trying to figure it out, why *Fedora* has not the static library `libm.a`, and if it is a fact, *which i should use*? 
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238870/why-there-is-no-static-library-for-math-functions) in **StackOverflow** i can simply install the *pkg* from `yum`, but is acceptable to think that *Fedora* have a replacement as default *lib* instead.No?

---

*edited*

I'm trying to compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fred(int arg)
{
    printf("fred: you passed %d\n", arg);
}
```

and the output is this:

```
$ gcc -o fred fred.c /usr/lib64/libm.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.2.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: En la función `_start':
(.text+0x20): referencia a `main' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
```

Test ggc with `lm` and `/usr/lib/libm.a` and `/usr/lib64/libm.a`

I've done all mencioned here and other posts, `yum install glibc-static` and checked for `/usr/lib64/libm.so`

---

edit

`repoquery --whatprovides /usr/lib64/libm.a`:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from fedora-cisco-openh264: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://codecs.fedoraproject.org/openh264/24/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for fedora-cisco-openh264
```

thanks.

Comment: Fedora does have libm.a.  As the link you list points out, libm.a is available from the glibc-static package.

Comment: Thanks, but why? if i understood correctly _libm.a_ is a standard library for maths. I'm not searching for a void() discussion. I think that if it is not included on the whole _distro_ it must be a reason. Do you know it?

Comment: libm.a is the static version of the math library and it is, obviously, included in the whole distro since it's in glibc-static.  Most people don't need static libraries so they are in a different package.  Note that the shared math library (libm.so) is found in glibc-devel.

Comment: Are you aware that unless you use `gcc -c`, the compiler expects a `main()` function? That's exactly what the error message said!

Comment: I had saw the output, onestly i'm not undertanding the compiler message, but in `man`: `When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking.  The
       "overall options" allow you to stop this process at an intermediate stage.  For example, the
       -c option says not to run the linker.  Then the output consists of object files output by
       the assembler.'

Comment: Is not my language and i must read very well before say anything!

Comment: ... but yes, i tested that you said, `gcc` had do a `bin` file, but is not possible to execute before check file permissions. It is very weird all of that!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things here....

1. You don't use any math functions in your little example, so you don't really need libm
2. If you *did* need libm, you don't really need the *static* `libm.a`. You can link against the dynamic one, and you can do this with `gcc -lm` rather than giving the file name directly.
3. If you *did* need `libm.a` for some reason, you could find it in the `glibc-static` package — but for a whole host of reasons this is not recommended.
4. As the error message says, what's really wrong is that you're missing a `main()` function. Try adding this to the bottom of your file:

   int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
        fred(1);
        fred(2);
        fred(42);
    }

and then compile with `gcc -o fred fred.c`