# Is it possible to compile a standalone Fortran executable in Linux?

Tags: linux, fortran, executable

For example, consider that I wrote a Fortran program in one computer and want to run it on another computer which may not have required libraries and/or has a different compiler (or even better, no Fortran compiler at all). Is it possible to create an executable with all its dependencies?

I am using gfortran (7.2.1) in Fedora 26 and sometimes use LAPACK routines in my code.

Using `-static` option with the program

```
program main
 write (*,*) 'Hello'
end
```

I get the output

```
gfortran -static a.f90 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is no error with `gfortran -static-libgfortran a.f90`

Comment: Read about static compilation and static linking. Not everything can be statically linked, there are issues with GLIBC. Just try compiling/linking with the `-static` flag first.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF. When I use `-static` flag (to print "hello world") it shows  `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm`, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm`, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc`.  What do I have to install for them? It does not show any error if I use `gfortran -static-libgfortran a.f90`.

Comment: Static linking of libgfortran is done via the extra switch. To link statically LAPACK, you must have a static LAPACK library available and also provide `-static` anyway. Please copy-paste your error in the main question as formatting of comments is terrible.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl, I edit my question.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can compile (on Debian) with `gfortran-7 -static a.f90`. Apparently in Fedora, you need the package `glibc-static` (see this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002773/fedora-dynamic-replacement-for-libm-astatic-lib). If that works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: It works @PierredeBuyl. `glibc-static` does the trick.

Comment: @Sumit when you visit Stack Overfow next, could you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fedora, gcc does not ship by default with static libraries.

You need to install the package `glibc-static` for the `-static` option to work, as hinted in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002773/fedora-dynamic-replacement-for-libm-astatic-lib).

Note that `-static-libgfortran` will only do static linking of the `libgfortran` library and that you must have static versions of your dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use Alpine Linux that uses [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/). I highly recommend using the docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) (only 5 Mb).